Failed to open stream: Permission denied while uploading image
Trying to upload an image in PHP, I'm receiving an error:
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../upload/ferrari_logo.jpg): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/mypage.php on line 108
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "/tmp/php8hHG6L" to "../upload/ferrari_logo.jpg" in /var/www/html/mypage.php on line 108
I know I have to change the permission in the upload folder. I just wanted to know if I change these permissions in Docker, Ubuntu terminal or PHP.
mypage.php
<div class="photo_column">
<form method="post" id="upload_form" action="mypage.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="about_me_photo">

    <?php
        $message = '';
        $moved = false;

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            if ($_FILES['photo_upload']['error'] === 0) {
                $temp = $_FILES['photo_upload']['tmp_name'];
                $path = '../upload/' . $_FILES['photo_upload']['name'];
                $moved = move_uploaded_file($temp, $path);
            } 

            if ($moved === true) {
                echo '<img id="about_me_img" src="' . $path . '"alt="">';
            } else {
                echo '<img id="about_me_img" src="" alt="">';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<img id="about_me_img" src="" alt="">';
        }

    ?>
            <div class="about_me_row">
                <input type="file" id="photo_upload" name="photo_upload" accept="image/*">
                <input type="submit" class="mypage_button"  id="submit_photo" value="Upload">
            </div>
            
        
    </div>
</form>
</div>

docker-compose.yml
version: "3.9"
services:
  php-apache:
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    build: './build/php'
    volumes:
      - ./app/public:/var/www/html
      - ./src:/var/www/src
      - ./config:/var/www/config
      - ./upload:/var/www/upload
      - ./img:/var/www/img
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    build: './build/mysql'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "commune"
    volumes:
      - dbData:/var/lib/mysql
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
volumes:
  app:
  src:
  config:
  upload:
  img:
  dbData:


Are you on a native-Linux host?  The container needs to run with a user: that matches the numeric user ID that owns the bind-mounted uploads folder.  Ideally this is a different user than owns the code; also consider fixing the significant security problem that allows the caller to overwrite any file in the container filesystem by providing a relative path as the name parameter.

I'm running localhost on Docker and Ubuntu. Yeah, I was going to add a regular expression for the filename. Should I add htmlspecialchars to the path variable. too? Thank you
